# laravel filter if else statement is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i trying to filter my product for price gender colors 
here is my working code when i use like that url localhost/category/tag?price=100

```
if (request()->has('gender')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('gender', request('gender'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('price')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('price', '<=', request('price'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('color')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('colors', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('color'));
      })->paginate(20);
  }
  if (request()->has('brand')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('brand'));
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  }
```

but getting error when url is localhost/category/tag

```
Undefined variable: products
```

i try to add else condition like that

```
if (request()->has('gender')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('gender', request('gender'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('price')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('price', '<=', request('price'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('color')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('colors', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('color'));
      })->paginate(20);
  }
  if (request()->has('brand')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('brand'));
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  }

  else  {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    }
```

its working on localhost/category/tag
but now filter not working on localhost/category/tag?price=100 
all data is showing sorry for my grammar

Comment: undefined variable on which line and page?

Comment: Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\swimwear2\resources\views\category\index.blade.php)
in f3407ad99fc10e7e2c6983562937345f02f5bf88.php (line 84)

Comment: @GauravRai Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\swimwear2\resources\views\category\index.blade.php)
in f3407ad99fc10e7e2c6983562937345f02f5bf88.php (line 84)

Comment: Post you full `controller` method, with `resources\views\category\index.bla‌​de.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically doing

```
if (request()->has('brand')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('brand'));
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  }

  else  {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    }
```

which makes the `else` statement work for `request()->has('brand')` 
wrap all your conditions in an `if` statement and the rest in an `else` statement

```
if(request()->has('gender')||request()->has('price')||request()->has('color')||request()->has('brand')){
if (request()->has('gender')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('gender', request('gender'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('price')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->where('price', '<=', request('price'))->get();
  }
  if (request()->has('color')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('colors', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('color'));
      })->paginate(20);
  }
  if (request()->has('brand')) {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
          $query->where('name', request('brand'));
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  }
}
  else  {
     $products = Product::withAllTags($tags)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    }
```